# How to build and then deploy express server in folder structure and TypeScript to Heroku

Tags: angular, typescript, express, heroku, deployment

I want to build and deploy my MEAN app to Heroku. I can deploy the front end part and then it works and is accessible on Heroku provided website, but I do not know how to correctly compile and build the server, which I have in folder structure and also in TypeScript. It looks like this - [myCodeStructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72eNP.png) where src folder is generated by Angular CLI.

I googled around, checked https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mean-apps-restful-api, but it was always with simple server.js file and NPM start with node server.js.

But how do I first transpile my server to javascript, build it, and then run it?

Comment: @Drenai thank you, I used the example to fix my package.json scripts, procfile and tsconfig in server folder and now I successfully deployed my app to heroku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by [Drenai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/271012/drenai) in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57546962/how-to-build-and-then-deploy-express-server-in-folder-structure-and-typescript-t/58973606#comment101559775_57546962):

> You should get an basic Express TS example project working first - for instance I notice you don't have a Procfile. Have a look at examples like this one [github.com/bergergit/mean-typescript-starter](https://github.com/bergergit/mean-typescript-starter). There is a lot of little things that can go wrong setting up Express build on Heroku if you don't follow a process, so having a basic example working first is a great place to start.

Answer (score 0):

It must be the same with react app:
https://medium.com/@chloechong.us/how-to-deploy-a-create-react-app-with-an-express-backend-to-heroku-32decfee6d18

Answer (score -1):

You can deploy a web app in heroku in the following steps

1. Setup an express server
2. Build your angular app using the command `ng build`
3. Point the public folder in the express using `path.join(__dirname, '../client/dist/project)` This will serve the dist files which are generated when we build the angular app via the express. If the express app is running at 3000 port, opening http://localhost:3000 will serve the content in this dist folder.
4. Copy the dist folder in the angular project into the express project's public folder.
5. Set the `npm start` command to `node .`
6. Deploy the app using heroku cli

This will help you in serving static files using express
https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Yes that is true. In some cases the frontend and backend are  different projects. If the project contains both front end and backend pointing the static path to the dist folder is enough.

Comment: Also i didn't see the code structure image. I just checked it now. Will edit the answer accordingly. Thanks @Drenai for pointing it out.